# Why am I unable to move pixels after they have been selected?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I've selected the below area in my image. I then switch to the move tool, but when I drag around the selection, the pixels that it had encompassed do not move with it. Would be great to know what I'm doing wrong :)

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: could your layer be locked?

Comment: 3 Questions that may or may not help us to expand on the problem: - Have you got the layer selected? - Is the layer locked as a background? - Have you rasterised the layer?

Answer (score 4):

The **Rectangular Marquee Tool (M)** strictly selects and area. With the Marquee tool still selected, clicking and dragging will move the marquee around without influencing any pixels.

If you want to move the selected pixels with the selection you must make sure you have the **Move Tool (V)** selected. Then simply click-and-drag the area around to move the selected pixels.

If for some reason the area still won't move it may be because you do not have the proper layer selected or perhaps you have multiple layers selected. Also ensure that your layer is not a text-based or smart object layer.

**EDIT**

In reply to your comment:

That is correct. You cannot move the selected pixels across multiple layers much like you can't paint on multiple layers simultaneously. Your alternatives would be to merge your layers (I'd back-up my non-merged layers first). Another method is you make your selection then go to `Select > Save Selection...`. Once your selection is saved you can use it to move one layer, then you may load the selection by going to `Select > Load Selection...` and then moving the other layer, etc.

I'm not familiar with other methods, though there may be other ones. It may also be possible to write a custom script that allows dragging selections across multiple layers.

Comment: Yes, I think it was because I didn't have any layers selected. I didn't realize this was necessary in order to move the pixels, as I thought the selection tool would "make active" pixels in any layers it encompassed? But I guess not. So, it will only move the selected pixels in whichever layers have been selected, is that right?

Comment: Check my edit I wrote in reply to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you don't have the ***Move Tool*** active. If you have, say, one of the Marquee Tools active then the selection will be moved around. Switch to the Move Tool to shuffle the selection of pixels around

Answer (score 0):

Agree on the questions asked previously.  Make sure you have a copy of the picture you are using so it's not a locked background.  And if you are still on the marquee tool, the pixels won't move with it.  You have to have the move tool selected to move the pixels.  It looks like you might be trying to crop?  IF so, try cropping what you want and rest will be deleted when you select what you want.

Comment: all of this has been said already

Answer (score 0):

I think if we insert a picture using PLACE option from the file menu then also we are not able to move the selected portion to  other place.